# Potential bug in HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode?

Tags: .net, base64

While tracing a bug I have found the following discrepancy between `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and `Convert.ToBase64String` in conversion to Base64 and back:

```
string test = "IN ('en-US')";
Console.WriteLine(HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)));
```

The result are slightly different: the first method has an additional trailing zero:

```
SU4gKCdlbi1VUycp0
SU4gKCdlbi1VUycp
```

JavaScript `btoa()` also gives me the value without trailing zero.

I understand that this zero is just for padding here, but is the second conversion still base64-compliant? Or should we refrain from using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` in favor of `Convert.ToBase64String` everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this SO post has more information about this issue, it seems like the number at the end indicates the number of `=` signs that were removed: [Encode URL from C#, decrypt URL in PHP (extra characters being added somehow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448683/encode-url-from-c-decrypt-url-in-php-extra-characters-being-added-somehow)

From the looks of it the `UrlTokenEncode` is especially to encode the tokens within the URL. A token should not contain characters which have a meaning within the URL, like `=`, `/` and `+`.

Here you can see the code that is used for the UrlTokenEncode: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/R/0e3cb83cf51ca334.html