# C#: base64url according to RFC4648

Tags: c#, base64, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm looking for a (fast) standard implementation for base64url according to [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) in C#.

I found [`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode(v=vs.110).aspx) but it looks like this doesn't follow RFC4648 (UrlTokenEncode adds a number at the end which indicates the number of `=` signs that were removed; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448683/encode-url-from-c-decrypt-url-in-php-extra-characters-being-added-somehow)).

Example:

base64 encoding:

> Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AA")); //returns  "QUE="

base64url encoding:

> HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AA"));
> //returns "QUE1" but I would expect "QUE"

Comment: Rather than just say "it looks like" can you give an example of what it does vs what you'd expect?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm sorry. I just added my concerns...

Comment: It's still fairly vague. Please give a *concrete* example: sample code containing sample data, with the actual output and expected output. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet: OK, I added an example with the expected outcome.

Comment: Right, that's more like it.

Comment: Simple solution - just remove the last character of the result using `Substring`. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Nope, sounds great. I was confused because it's not documented on the Microsoft page...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like `System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` does the right thing *except* for the extra character for padding. So you should be able to do:

```
string customBase64 = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(data);
string rfc4648 = customBase64.Substring(0, customBase64.Length - 1);
```

However, you should add unit tests to check that it really does use the RFC 4648 alphabet (and in the same way as RFC 4648). It's somewhat surprising that the docs are so sparse :(

Comment: In case you want to decode (`UrlTokenDecode`) Jon's `rfc4648` you need to add the extra character again: `if (rfc4648.Length%4 != 0) rfc4648 += (4 - rfc4648.Length%4);`

Comment: @Dunken: I believe you should add it regardless of the length - but with 0 instead of 4, if it would otherwise be 4.

Comment: Added gist [Base64UrlExtensions](https://gist.github.com/dariusdamalakas/b9570c36481aea6dd24d), hope this is useful to anyone.  This has both encode and decode as extensions on `string`.

Comment: @Darius doesn't seem to work in .NET Core, the HttpServerUtility doesn't exist there.